# Use client secret hashed value

Tags: c#, identityserver4

I am following this doc http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/clients.html
which says to create a client with ClientSecrets = "secret".Sha256() and I get the hashed value is of K7gNU3sdo+OL0wNhqoVWhr3g6s1xYv72ol/pe/Unols=

When I try to use the client with the hashed value:
`options.ClientSecret = "K7gNU3sdo+OL0wNhqoVWhr3g6s1xYv72ol/pe/Unols=";` 
I get an error saying "invalid_client". 
But If I use `options.ClientSecret = "secret";` it works.

How can I use my client with the hashed value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hashing is for storage. So when you data store gets compromised, the attacked cannot easily get to the real secrets.

The client sends secrets unhashed.

Comment: What's the question? A client is a piece of software (not an instance of a piece of a software) so usually you would have many users all using the same client ... e.g. a webpage, or an app etc.